# Problem with dynamic image in MS Access report

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-reports

I have a report for printing labels on a grid of let's say 3 by 6 on A4 paper. These are peel-off labels, which can be printed either full sheet or just 1, depending on needs.

The report's record source is a query, which contains always 18 records (to cover a 3x6 grid), and 3 columns: [ID] (1-18), [LabelText], and [Path]. Out of these 18 records sometimes all 18 LabelText and Path are populated, but sometimes only the first few (and the rest is empty **""** ), but also it could be that say first 4 are empty, then 6 have data and the rest 8 are empty. ID is always populated with numbers 1 to 18. This is done so that labels on A4 are not wasted.

Each printed label should contain a different image based on the file path given in column [Path]. This is achieved with the Detail On Format event

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
   Me.Image0.Picture = Me.path
End Sub
```

All works with a problem.

1. If all 18 labels are filled, all is correct
2. If say first 3 records are filled, then the first 3 labels get the correct Image, but all the rest of the 15 labels also get the last image (from label 3)
3. If say first 3 records are empty and the next 3 records have data and the rest is empty, then the first 3 labels have no image (as it should be) labels 4-6 have a correct image and the rest again get the last image (from label 6)

I tried many different "If/Else" options in the On Format event, but always get the same result. There must a simple solution, but I am not seeing it.

Comment: Empty is usually `Null`, not "". Try `Me.Image0.Picture = Nz(Me.path, "")`.

Comment: I explicitly set it to "", so that I would get Me.Image0.Picture = ""

Answer (score 1):

As you have the path (even empty), you could use a *bound* image control.

Simply set its ControlSource to: Path

For an example, see the demo at my project [VBA.PictureUrl](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.PictureUrl).

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing, but for records which has no path, I still get random (last) image.

Comment: Not exactly. Property _ControlSource_ and property _Picture_ are not the same.